# Java Application Interacting with Flash on Web Application

Tags: java, php, python, actionscript-3, flash

Is there anyway I can make a Java application communicate with a Flash Player (application) that is on a website? The flash application is quite dynamic, meaning the data changes as i refresh and visit different pages. In fact the page itself is fully flash.

Where should i be looking at to get this working?

I'm thinking how can i even retrieve the text / objects from this flash and then send a action(click, text ) .

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

GraniteDS will allow you to access your java objects via the Flex framework.

Comment: I can use a simple solution which is to listen to POST/ GET request? Since i believe that flash application does use post/get , xml file.

Comment: but the question is also can i listen without a browser? or isit a must to listen through a browser